# View Layout_Margin doesn't work inside the FrameLayout

Tags: android, margin, android-framelayout

I have a `frameLayout` and inside this layout there are several Views, and I want to margin each view from the top to a specific distance .
I have tried the following code, but it seems that it doesn't work

```
   FrameLayout lytBoard = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.lytBoard);
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
   params.setMargins((int)board.cells.get(i).x1, (int)board.cells.get(i).y1, 0, 0);
   CellView cv = new CellView(getApplicationContext());
   cv.setLayoutParams(params);
   lytBoard.addView(cv);
```

Cell View class:

```
public class CellView extends View {

    public CellView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int size = Math.min(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
        setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
    }

}
```

Comment: It is not a good practice to add views in frame layout.You can not, rather than this add in relative layout

Answer (score 1):

You are setting to the `CellView`, subclass of `View`,  a `layoutParams` of the type `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. In the [definition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams%28android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) of the method in `View`, the method `setLayoutParams` receives params of the type `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` and `ViewGroup` does not contains a margin property, so this may be the cause of the problem.

You can try to subclass `LinearLayout` instead of `View`.